# Open Page Redirect Issue

Tags: apex, security, redirect

We are using a third party company to scan our salesforce code for SOQL Injection and Vulnerability issues with open page redirects. The below code is flagged as a vulnerability.

```
    Id id = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    String html;                                                                        
    **if (Utilities.isId(id) && !String.valueOf(id).startsWith('/')) {**                
        html = new PageReference('/' + id + '/p').getContent().toString();
    } else {
        html = new PageReference('/' + '/p').getContent().toString();                   
    }
```

I am checking whether the variable id is an instance of Salesforce Id using the Utilities.isId method and also checking to see there is no forward slash at the beginning and I am adding the forward slash while constructing the html String variable. However, this fix is still flagged as vulnerable code.

Can someone help?

The implementation of isId method is below.

```
public boolean isId(String strId) {
    return strId instance Id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a false positive, assuming `Utilities.isId` is safe. There's really not much of a need for the complicated check, though, as the following would suffice:

```
String recordId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
if(recordId instanceOf Id) {
  ...
```

An ID can never start with a `/`, so if this passes, it's an ID.

Comment: implementation of isId method is added to the original post.

Comment: @BalajiPooruli Which is basically what I wrote, except it really doesn't need to be a method, if you ask me. Still, yes, this should be perfectly safe.